# Repository and Branches as parameters in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, repository, branch

I Want to create a JOB that have as parameters the name of the repository, and once this parameter is set, then the second parameter (branches) is shown as list of available GIT branches in the selected repository.

Thank for your help.
Reda.

Answer (score 1):

You can get these parameters using this Groovy code:

1. Get repository name:

   ```
   def rpository_name = scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl().tokenize('/')[3].split("\\.")[0]
   ```
2. Get list branches:

   ```
   def branches = git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)'
   ```

If this code is not working you can use this script: [Jenkins groovy script which lists remote branches.
Raw](https://gist.github.com/vStone/f04780d273b2b378dc99)

Comment: But I want that I extract the branches list from the choosen repository in the first parameter

Comment: @MohamedRedaArherbi with the command `def branches = git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)'` you can extract the branches for your current git repository, do you need to extract the info from another repository that is not your actually repository?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need to extract branches from a repository that is selected in the previous paramater. So Dyanmically the branch list will change based on the value of the first parameter (repository). Thanks